# Inference about parameter $\theta$ be same?

Tags: distributions, self-study, references, inference, sample

Let $\mathbf x$ be a sample point and $T(\mathbf x)$ be a statistic of $\mathbf x$.

Similarly, let $\mathbf y$ be a sample point and $T(\mathbf y)$ be a statistic of $\mathbf y$.

In the book [Statistical Inference by George Casella](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534243126), it is written that :

*If $\mathbf x$  and $\mathbf y$ are two sample points such that $T(\mathbf x)=T(\mathbf y)$, then the inference about the parameter $\theta$ would be the same.*

I have not understood the statement. $T(\mathbf x)= T(\mathbf y)$ does not imply $\mathbf x= \mathbf y$. Then why should the inference about parameter $\theta$ be same ?

Answer (score 4):

This is only true when $T$ is a *sufficient* statistic.

Sufficiency implies that knowing the value of the statistic provides just as much information as having the original data points, given some assumption about how the data was generated.  (So a statistic may be sufficient for some assumed data generating processes but insufficient for others).

Consider 5 independent flips of the same coin to learn about its bias.  Making a Binomial assumption about this data implies that only the *number* of heads and tails are relevant for inference about the proportion parameter representing the true bias of the coin.  That's because any *ordering* of 3 heads and 2 tails imply the same likelihood function, and therefore the same maximum and curvature.  That's what makes these statistics sufficient.

See [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic) for some more discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Because all inference we do is based on information we got from statistics, and since they are the same the inference must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true in general.
This is true if and only if $T$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ - (by definition)
Actually, your citation comes from the definition of Sufficiency Principle from that book